# Office 365 REST API me/events no longer working

Tags: json, api, rest, outlook

I *thought* I had the Office REST API call: https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/events working (a few days ago, I *really* thought it was), but now, although it returns an HTTP response status of 200, the payload is malformed JSON saying:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#Me/Events",
"value": [
    {
        "error": {
            "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
            "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
        }
    }
```

(Note that the final two characters "]}", which would make it valid JSON, appear to be missing.)

Has anybody any idea what is going on?

Are they messing about with the API?

The call to me/events is one of their primary examples, here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations in the section entitled "Specifying an item in an entity collection": "For example, to get the events from the user's primary calendar, send a GET request to the following URL:
https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/events"

Mike Peat

Answer (score 2):

It's an Outlook REST API issue. We already escalated the problem with Outlook API people and they're working on that.
We'll let you know once it's fixed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this seems to be a general problem
My implementation with Office 365 Calendar API worked until 13.09.
Suddenly it doesn't return any appointment items anymore.

Comment: P. S. I've opened a support request on the MSDN Support website to get the issue resolved.

Comment: Thanks @Franz.  I've been adding comments to the bottom of their reference pages, using the "Was this page helpful to you?" button, whenever I come across something wrong in their various APIs, but I'm not sure that anybody at MS actually reads what is said there.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/events has started working again.  Thank you Outlook REST API Team.  :)

Answer (score 0):

for me it still doesn't work.
I'm using the managed API like:

OutlookServicesClient outlookClient = await this.GetOutlookServicesClient();

```
        var folderItemResult = await outlookClient.Me.Events
            .Where(e => 
            e.Start.Value >= uTCFrom &&
            e.Start.Value <= uTCTo)
            .ExecuteAsync();
```

As soon there are Items in the calendar ExecuteAsync fails after requesting the authorizationtoken. If there is no entry the call to ExecuteAsync after requesting the authorizationtoke is successful.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded the Office 365 API Multi Tenant Sample from Git Hub which reads contacts.
I configured it and run it to see if it works with Contacts and it worked fine.
Afterwards I changed the code to read all Events from my Mailbox.
Like in the initial request in this post there is the following error message

[DataServiceClientException: Fehler beim Verarbeiten des Antwortdatenstroms. Es ist ein Fehler mit der folgenden Nachricht auf dem Server aufgetreten:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

Is there any difference to the managed Office 365 API than calling the rest api myself or is there anything else that needs to be fixed in the Office 365 API?

Here is the complete Stack Trace:

[ODataErrorException: Aus der Nutzlast wurde ein Fehler gelesen. Weitere Informationen finden Sie in der Error-Eigenschaft.]
   Microsoft.OData.Core.Json.BufferingJsonReader.ProcessObjectValue() +188
   Microsoft.OData.Core.Json.BufferingJsonReader.ReadNextAndCheckForInStreamError() +95
   Microsoft.OData.Core.Json.BufferingJsonReader.ReadInternal() +227
   Microsoft.OData.Core.Json.BufferingJsonReader.Read() +5
   Microsoft.OData.Core.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightEntryAndFeedDeserializer.ReadFeedContentStart() +56
   Microsoft.OData.Core.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.ReadFeedStart(ODataFeed feed, SelectedPropertiesNode selectedProperties) +24
   Microsoft.OData.Core.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.ReadAtStartImplementationSynchronously(DuplicatePropertyNamesChecker duplicatePropertyNamesChecker) +175
   Microsoft.OData.Core.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.ReadAtStartImplementation() +69
   Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataReaderCore.ReadImplementation() +42
   Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataReaderCore.ReadSynchronously() +5
   Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataReaderCore.InterceptException(Func`1 action) +96
   Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataReaderCore.Read() +68
   Microsoft.OData.Client.Materialization.ODataReaderWrapper.Read() +18
   Microsoft.OData.Client.Materialization.FeedAndEntryMaterializerAdapter.TryRead() +30

[DataServiceClientException: Fehler beim Verarbeiten des Antwortdatenstroms. Es ist ein Fehler mit der folgenden Nachricht auf dem Server aufgetreten:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Microsoft.OData.Client.Materialization.FeedAndEntryMaterializerAdapter.TryRead() +97
   Microsoft.OData.Client.Materialization.FeedAndEntryMaterializerAdapter.TryStartReadFeedOrEntry() +13
   Microsoft.OData.Client.Materialization.FeedAndEntryMaterializerAdapter.TryReadFeedOrEntry(Boolean lazy, ODataFeed& feed, MaterializerEntry& entry) +20
   Microsoft.OData.Client.Materialization.FeedAndEntryMaterializerAdapter.Read() +138
   Microsoft.OData.Client.Materialization.ODataReaderEntityMaterializer.ReadNextFeedOrEntry() +10
   Microsoft.OData.Client.Materialization.ODataEntityMaterializer.ReadImplementation() +51
   Microsoft.OData.Client.MaterializeAtom.MoveNextInternal() +348
   Microsoft.OData.Client.MaterializeAtom.MoveNext() +68
   System.Linq.d__1`1.MoveNext() +176
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +387
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   Microsoft.OData.ProxyExtensions.PagedCollection`2..ctor(DataServiceContextWrapper context, QueryOperationResponse`1 qor) +53
   Microsoft.OData.ProxyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass38`2.<ExecuteAsync>b__36(IAsyncResult r) +167
   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) +86
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.OData.ProxyExtensions.<ExecuteAsync>d__3a`2.MoveNext() +686
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
   O365_WebApp_MultiTenant.Controllers.<Index>d__0.MoveNext() in D:\Projekte\Office 365\O365-WebApp-MultiTenant-master\O365-WebApp-MultiTenant\O365-WebApp-MultiTenant\Controllers\ContactsController.cs:65
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129